# Summarize data based on last 3 months in r

Tags: r

The data is as follows:

```
a <- rep('A',6)
b <- rep('B',6)
c <- c('2020-10-01','2020-09-01','2020-01-01','2020-03-10','2020-11-01','2020-08-01')
d <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)


df1 <- df %>%
       group_by(a,b) %>%
       summarise(d=mean(d)) ###### Summarise 'd' of only the latest 3 months
```

The columns 'a' and 'b' should be grouped together and the column 'd' should be mean summarized based on the Date column which has the latest 3 months.

Each group by should have the last 3 months. Can't filter out last 3 months for the entire data. Each group by case should have latest 3 months

"The last 3 months. So '2020-11-01', '2020-10-01' and ' 2020-09-01' should be selected. As they are the latest 3 months in the df"

Comment: what is your expected result? what _exactly_ does "latest 3 months" mean?

Comment: The last 3 months. So '2020-11-01', '2020-10-01' and ' 2020-09-01' should be selected. As they are the latest 3 months in the df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R. We split the data by the `a` and `b` factors, then select last three months (for each a/b grouping), then perform average based on latest three months for each a/b grouping, and `rbind` back together:

```
df$c <- as.Date(df$c) # convert to date

do.call("rbind", 
        lapply(split(df, list(df$a, df$b)),
               FUN = function(dat) aggregate(d ~ a + b, 
                                     data = tail(dat[order(dat$c),], 3), 
                                     FUN = mean)))
```

Using a similar idea (grouping, ordering, and then taking tail) with **`data.table`**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(c), tail(.SD, 3), .(a, b)][,.(mean_d = mean(d)), .(a, b)]

   a b   mean_d
1: A B 2.666667
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is your expected answer, you can subset the dates before you group.

```r
library(tidyverse)

a <- rep('A',6)
b <- rep('B',6)
c <- c('2020-10-01','2020-09-01','2020-01-01','2020-03-10','2020-11-01','2020-08-01')
d <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)

df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(c = c %>% as.Date()) %>% 
  group_by(a,b) %>% 
  arrange(desc(c)) %>% 
  slice(1:3) %>% 
  summarise(mean = d %>% mean())
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'a' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#> # Groups:   a [1]
#>   a     b      mean
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 A     B      2.67
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You need to `group_by` before `slice`

Comment: Yes @bouncyball  you're right, I've edited my code. Since in this case, both columns has only one category it didn't affect the output.